# Python dictionary key/value with prefixes - what's the prefix for?

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I've seen a Python dict looks like this lately:

```
test1 = {u'user':u'user1', u'user_name':u'alice'}
```

This confuses me a bit, what is the `u` before the key/value pair for? Is it some sort of prefix? How is this different:

```
test2 = {'user':'user1', 'user_name':'alice'}
```

I've tried to play with both test1 and test2; they don't seem different at all. Can somebody explain what the prefix is for?

```
>>> test1 = {u'user':u'user1', u'user_name':u'alice'}
>>> test2 = {'user':'user1', 'user_name':'alice'} 
>>> print test1[u'user']
user1
>>> print test1['user']
user1
>>> print test2['user']
user1
>>> print test2[u'user']
```

Comment: `u` stands for [unicode](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: [Python-Unicode](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

Comment: when you get to databases, they convert your string into unicode, so unless you actually come to a point where you deal with unicodes you shouldn't have to stress over this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Python 2, you have to force Unicode character to remain in Unicode.

So, `u` prevents the text to translate to ASCII. (remaining as unicode)

For example, this won't work in Python 2:

```
'ô SO'.upper() == 'Ô SO''
```

Unless you do this:

```
u'ô SO'.upper() == 'Ô SO'
```

You can read more on this: [**DOCS**](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings)

Some history:  [**PEP 3120**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/)

Comment: Thanks :) is there any docs covering this? can you give me an code example? where I can have text translated to ASCII。

Comment: @Shengjie you can translate a character to ascii value using [ord( )](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord). For example, `ord('a')` will return `97`

Answer (score 3):

`u'unicode string'` will make the string a type [unicode](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), where without the prefix the string is an ASCII type string `'ASCII string'`.